# How to exclude "DEBUG" without throws "BUG" in grep

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I trying to build a command to grep common list of error keywords(e.g. `bug occured!`, `error`, `exception`), but need to exclude common keywords too (e.g. `DEBUG` tag) without throws the matched line. This command should robust enough to handle miscellaneous of source/log.

Let's say I have this source:

```
$ cat dummy.log 
12345   DEBUG   debug.log abc
!DEBUG
!bug
!debug
DEBUG noop
12345 DEBUG bug occured
please report BUG to me
the filename is critical_bug.log
bug should be fix.
noop
throws error
a stuff
b otherstuff
c otherstuff stuff
```

This command will not work because it excluded the `bug` lines(i.e. `12345 DEBUG bug occured`) which contains `DEBUG`:

```
$ cat -v dummy.log | nl | grep -Ei 'bug|stuff|error' | grep -Evi 'DEBUG|otherstuff'
 3  !bug
 7  please report BUG to me
 8  the filename is critical_bug.log
 9  bug should be fix.
11  throws error
12  a stuff
```

Change the order of pipe also same as above:

```
$ cat -v dummy.log | nl | grep -Evi 'DEBUG|otherstuff' | grep -Ei 'bug|stuff|error'
 3  !bug
 7  please report BUG to me
 8  the filename is critical_bug.log
 9  bug should be fix.
11  throws error
12  a stuff
```

Try to use `^` in grep (***[UPDATE]** wrong, `^` is not for exclude*), but it included the `DEBUG noop` which doesn't contains `bug` (note: all of the filter should case insensitive, e.g. I want to accept `BUG occured!` and exclude `debug.log`):

```
 $ cat -v dummy.log | nl | grep -Ei 'bug|stuff|error|^DEBUG|^otherstuff'
 1  12345   DEBUG   debug.log abc
 2  !DEBUG
 3  !bug
 4  !debug
 5  DEBUG noop
 6  12345 DEBUG bug occured
 7  please report BUG to me
 8  the filename is critical_bug.log
 9  bug should be fix.
11  throws error
12  a stuff
13  b otherstuff
14  c otherstuff stuff
```

I can't customized to exclude only `debug` if I only use `-w` (e.g. `the filename is critical_bug.log` failed to include):

```
$ grep -wnEi 'bug|stuff|error' dummy.log 
3:!bug
6:12345 DEBUG bug occured
7:please report BUG to me
9:bug should be fix.
11:throws error
12:a stuff
14:c otherstuff stuff
```

My expected output (Note: I need to keep matched color and original line number):

```
$ grep -wnEi 'bug|stuff|error' dummy.log 
3:!bug
6:12345 DEBUG bug occured
7:please report BUG to me
8:the filename is critical_bug.log
9:bug should be fix.
11:throws error
12:a stuff
14:c otherstuff stuff
```

Is it possible make this in `grep` or alternative command?

Comment: Does your `grep` have a `-w` (`--word-regexp`) option?

Comment: @steeldriver I think so,  `-w` display in `--help`.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, I noticed `grep -Ei 'bug|stuff|error|^DEBUG|^otherstuff' -w` achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @steeldriver And I noticed I must keep my `| nl | `, can't simply use `grep -n` to shows number of line.

Comment: please note ^ mean begin of line (not exclude) and grep work on files no need to pipe cat

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, what's the correct way to negate? `'bug|stuff|error|!DEBUG|!otherstuff'` (treat as literal) or `'bug|stuff|error|\!DEBUG|\!otherstuff'` not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming GNU `grep` (the default on Linux) you could use PCRE mode and [negative lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -niP '(?<!de)bug|(?<!other)stuff|error' dummy.log 
3:!bug
6:12345 DEBUG bug occured
7:please report BUG to me
8:the filename is critical_bug.log
9:bug should be fix.
11:throws error
12:a stuff
14:c otherstuff stuff
```

The options used are:

```
-n, --line-number
    Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within 
        its input file.

-i, --ignore-case
    Ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data, so that
    characters that differ only in case match each other.

-P, --perl-regexp
    Interpret  PATTERNS  as  Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).
    This option is experimental when combined with the  -z  (--null-data)
    option, and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

The magic happens in the lookbehind. The general format is `(?!<foo)bar` and this means "match `bar` but **only** if it isn't preceded by `foo`". So `(?<!de)bug` will match `bug` unless it comes after `de` and `(?<!other)stuff` will match `stuff` unless it comes after `other`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work if a line containing `_bug.log`. I want to customize the text I don't want,

Comment: @Fruit no, but why should it? Your question is looking for the work `bug` by itself. I that's not the case, please edit your question and clarify. What should happen with `_bug.log`? Should that line be kept? Should it be skipped? This is giving the exact same output as your example, so if this isn't actually what you want, you need to let us know.

Comment: Thanks, I added my expected output.

Comment: @alecxs with GNU `grep` and PCREs, you can use negative lookbehinds: `printf 'debug\na bug\nbugles\njitterbugger\n' | grep -P '(?<!de)bug'`

Comment: @Fruit thanks for the edit. See updated answer. Note that this will match things like `differentstuff` and `jitterbuger` (cases where `bug` occurs in the middle of a word). You haven't mentioned those though, so I don't know if you actually do want to match them.

Comment: `(?<!de|not a |no)bug` worked for me if I want to add multiple patterns.

Comment: @Fruit yeah, you can't give options, no. If you need that kind of complexity, I would just script it and stop playing around with `grep` and regexes.

Comment: my bad, `(?<!de)` is for before the string, how about after the string, e.g. `bug(?<! fixed)` ? This answer should cover this common case. `debug` is just an example, I have a lot of string(prefix and postfix) to add.

Comment: @Fruit it's kind of hard to cover all the cases if you don't tell us what the cases are! Where did `bug fixed` come from? It's not in your input file, it's not in your desired output. We can only answer what you actually ask. Anyway, what you are looking for is called a `negative lookahead` and the syntax for that would be `bug(?! fixed)`. Also, since I mentioned scripting, you can try to extend this: `printf 'bug\na bug\nnot a bug\ndebug\nnobug\n' | perl -ne 'print if(/(.{0,6})bug/ && ($1 !~ /not a $/ && $1 !~ /de$/ && $1 !~ /no$/)); '`.

Comment: Thanks. my mistake because not using `other` as postfix example for `otherstuff`. Yes, `(?<!de|not a |no)bug(?!.txt|txt)` worked for me for prefix and postfix(I don't know `<` is not required for postfix), thanks.

Comment: @Fruit oh, cool! I didn't think you could give multiple options of different length like that!